# Creating Google Sheets file with REST request

Tags: json, rest, google-api, request, content-type

I'm really new to the concept of REST and I've been trying to work with Google's Sheets, Drive, and Classroom APIs. I have been able to pull classroom roster data, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this issue with a parseError and Googling for hours hasn't helped.

```
let init = {
      method: "POST",
      async: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
      },
      "contentType": "application/json"
    };
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key='+apicall, init) 
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(init);
    });
```

The console logs are so I can view the data, this clearly isn't going to be in the final project, but every time I send the request, it throws me error 400 parseError, which [Google clearly tells me is a Content-Type error](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#400_Bad_Request), but I specified that it's JSON, so I'm a bit confused. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own answer after some tinkering around. I changed the `Content-Type` to `application/javascript`. Even though it wasn't what I was looking for, it threw an error saying to change the `fetch` URI. I tried, and it made a Javascript file containing nothing but `[object Object]`. I was confused so I changed it all back. I read up some more on JSON formatting when I came across [this quote](http://googleappscripting.com/json/):

> When you have a Javascript object, serializing JSON is very easy:

Which lead me to remember it made the empty Javascript object... ohhhh! The body information wasn't being formatted as JSON data, but rather as a Javascript array! So then I guess I should...

```
var bodydata = {"name": "New spreadsheet", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"};
    let init = {
      method: "POST",
      async: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodydata)
```

...convert the Javascript data into a JSON string!

And it worked! It was very satisfying, but I figured I'd answer my own question on here for anyone else just learning REST APIs and figuring out stuff on their own like me!